# Different form action according to different submit button

Tags: javascript, forms

If I have a form which have 2 buttons , and when I click Button1 then it will be `action="submit1.php"` , if Button2 then `action="submit2.php"`.

I tried this:

```
  <script language="javascript">

  function Button1()
   {
     document.Form1.action = "submit1.php"   
     document.Form1.target = "iframe1";    
     document.Form1.submit();        

   }

  function Button2()
   {
    document.Form1.action = "submit2.php" ;
    document.Form1.target = "iframe2";    
    document.Form1.submit();       
   }

 </script>
```

Somewhere in the `<body>`:

```
  <div style="visibility:hidden">
  <iframe NAME="iframe1" WIDTH="40" HEIGHT="40"></iframe>
  <iframe NAME="iframe2" WIDTH="40" HEIGHT="40"></iframe>
  </div>
```

And in the form:

```
  <form name="Form1" id="Form1" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="Button1" onclick="Button1();">
  <input type="submit" name="Button2" onclick="Button2();">
  </form>
```

It's not working , am I make anything wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you saying nothing happens when you click the buttons, or something happens but the wrong thing (if so what?), or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn I;m so sorry for my late response.If I click the button it will just like refreshing the page.However it fixed now , thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two issues

EITHER

change the buttons to type="button"

OR

remove the submit from the functions

Plain JS (using the simpler forms access):

```
<script language="javascript">
function Button(theButton) {
  var theForm = theButton.form;
  if (theButton.name=="Button1") {
    theForm.action = "submit1.php"   
    theForm.target = "iframe1";    
  }
  else {
    theForm.action = "submit2.php"   
    theForm.target = "iframe2";    
  }
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="nojsavailable.php">
  <input type="submit" name="Button1" onclick="Button(this);" />
  <input type="submit" name="Button2" onclick="Button(this);" />
</form>
```

Unobtrusively (recommended):

```
<script language="javascript">
window.onload=function() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByName("button");
  for (var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick=function() {
      var idx = i+1;
      var theForm = this.form;
      theForm.action = "submit"+idx+".php"   
      theForm.target = "iframe"+idx;    
    }
  }
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="nojsavailable.php">
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button1" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button2" />
</form>
```

Comment: So sorry for my late response , and really thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

User small nameing for the functions. Javascript seems to be confusing Button1 function with Button1 object. So your solution would be

```
 <script language="javascript">

  function button1()
   {
     document.Form1.action = "submit1.php"   
     document.Form1.target = "iframe1";    
     document.Form1.submit();        

   }

  function button2()
   {
    document.Form1.action = "submit2.php" ;
    document.Form1.target = "iframe2";    
    document.Form1.submit();       
   }

 </script>
```

and in form

```
<form name="Form1" id="Form1" method="post">
  <input type="button" id="Button1" name="button1()" />
  <input type="button" id="Button2" name="button2()" />
</form>
```

Comment: I agree - completely irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `element.setAttribute('attributeName','attributeValue');` instead. Also, you don't need to use `form.submit();` in this case, the submit button will submit the form anyway, just need to `return true` in the onclick method.

Try:

```
 function Button1()
   {
     document.getElementById('Form1').setAttribute('action',"submit1.php");
     document.getElementById('Form1').setAttribute('target',"iframe1");

   }

  function Button2()
   {
     document.getElementById('Form2').setAttribute('action',"submit2.php");
     document.getElementById('Form2').setAttribute('target',"iframe2");   
   }
```

Comment: There should be no problem with setting the [`action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.action) _property_ directly. (Though I definitely prefer to use `.getElementById()`.)

Comment: "Don't need" should be "not allowed"

Comment: yep, in fact if he does so he'll be submitting the form twice

Comment: So sorry for my late response,I get the solution and still thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

this would be your final code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script language="javascript">

  function button1()
   {
     document.Form1.action = "http://www.google.com"   
     document.Form1.target = "iframe1";    
     document.Form1.submit();        

   }

  function button2()
   {
    document.Form1.action = "http://www.yahoo.com" ;
    document.Form1.target = "iframe2";    
    document.Form1.submit();       
   }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="Form1" id="Form1" method="post">

  <input type="button" value="btn1" name="Button1" onclick="button1()">
  <input type="button" value="btn2" name="Button2" onclick="button2()">  

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need to answer twice. - the type="button" has already been discussed an hour ago and is one reason why it did not work.

Comment: So sorry for my late response,and still thanks for your reply.